# Windows Live JavaScript SDK authentication/login (OAuth) handling trouble

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, windows-live

I'm currently looking at the *Microsoft Live JavaScript SDK* (OneDrive mostly) and I'm having some problems with the OAuth login process. I am using the [examples found on MSDN pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631819.aspx) to log-in/authenticate but there is something weird going on.

Whenever I do `WS.init()` my page refreshes... and when I call the same function again I get the popup window I expected. I click to accept, but the popup does not close and instead load the page which I came from.

I normally would expect no redirect here at all and the popup window should just close normally leaving me on the page from which I came.

I have ensured that my redirect URI (account.live.com application settings) is the exact same as the hostname I am developing this thing on. I faced a similar problem with [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/)'s OAuth process, but that was simply solved by adding a *[OAuth reciever page](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/test/html/oauth_receiver.html)*. So I get the feeling that I'm missing something here. Anyone else familiar with how this works ? I'm having trouble finding any info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I [finally found my answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826547.aspx). Turns out Windows Live SDK has the same solution as dropbox.js (which I mentioned in my question).